# Thoughts on our approach to validation in a distributed application with multiple clients

Tags: c#, wcf, validation, domain-driven-design

I'm here to hear your thoughts on the approach we have taken to validation so far. We're still early in the development process so we can still change it. Validation is very important for this application and our clients, so we need to find the most optimal way. Let me describe what we have done so far...

We're building this application that is going to be consumed by different clients. We do not control all the clients and so there are strict requirements to validation in all layers. We do control some of the client applications, one being a WPF application used by ~100 users. From this application, the workflow is as follows:

```
|                     Client                   |                                 Backend Service                             |
ViewModel -> ClientRepository -> ServiceClient -> Service (WCF) -> ApplicationService -> DomainModel -> Repository -> Database
```

We see the following as candidates for performing validation.

- Client: ViewModel validation, for supporting the UI with required fields, lengths, etc.
- Backend: Service request DTO validation, because we can't rely on the clients to always supply 100% valid values.
- Backend: Domain model entity validation. We do not want our entities to ever end up in a invalid state, and therefore each entity will contain different checks when operations are performed.
- Backend: Database validation, such as failing constraints (FK, uniqueness, lenghts, etc.)

The clients ViewModel validation is pretty obvious and for our own clients, as many errors as possible should be corrected there before reaching the service. Can't speak for other applications consuming our service though, and the worst should be assumed.

Service request DTO's should be validated primarily for the case of third party applications and mistakes in our own client. Ensuring that the request is correct, can prevent the error popping up later while processing the request, thus ensuring a more effective service. Like the ViewModel validation, this comes down to required fields, lengths and formats (e.g. email) of the different properties.

The entities in the domain model should themselves ensure that they will always have completely valid attributes/properties, we are achieving this like this, taking the `Customer` entity as an example.

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    private Customer() : base() { }

    public Customer(Guid id, string givenName, string surname)
        : this(id, givenName, null, surname) { }

    public Customer(Guid id, string givenName, string middleName, string surname)
        : base(id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(givenName))
            throw new ArgumentException(GenericErrors.StringNullOrEmpty, "givenName");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(surname))
            throw new ArgumentException(GenericErrors.StringNullOrEmpty, "surname");

        GivenName = givenName.Trim();
        Surname = surname.Trim();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middleName))
            MiddleName = middleName.Trim();
    }
}
```

Now while this ensures that the attributes are valid, a `CustomerValidator` class validates the Customer class as a whole, ensuring that it is in a valid state and not only has valid attributes. The `CustomerValidator` is implemented using the FluentValidation framework. It is called in the application service before committing the customer object to the database.

What do you think of our approach so far?

What I am a bit concerned about, is the usage of exceptions being thrown all over the place. E.g. `ArgumentException` the example above, but also `InvalidOperationException` in case of the call to some method that is not permitted in the current state of the object.

Hopefully, these exception will be thrown very rarely, because the service request DTO is validated, and therefore I'm thinking that it might be okay? For example when the service request DTO is validated, argument exceptions should never be raised, unless there is an error somewhere in the validation. Thus you can say that these argument checks in the domain model acts as an extra layer of security. `InvalidOperationException` on the other hand, can be raised if the client calls a service method that calls a method on the Customer object that is unavailable in its current state (and thus it should fail).

What do you think? If it all sounds okay, how can I appropriately inform the user through WCF when something fails? Be it an `ArgumentException`, `InvalidOperationException`, or an exception containing a list of errors (thrown by the ApplicationService after validation the customer object using the CustomerValidator class). Should I somehow catch all these exceptions and turn them into some general fault exception thrown by WCF and thus the client can react to it and inform the user what happened?

I'm interested in hearing your thoughts on our approach. We're in the beginning of building this rather large application, and we really want to find a good way of performing validation. There are some really critical parts in our application where the data correctness is very important, so validation is important!

Answer (score 2):

My own opinion is that the domain consistency should be handled by the domain. So no need for `CustomerValidator` of sorts.

As for exceptions, you should consider that, `ArgumentNullException` apart, they should be terms of the ubiquitous language (for a deeper explanation see http://epic.tesio.it/2013/03/04/exceptions-are-terms-ot-the-ubiquitous-language.html).

BTW, even if all your DTO have been previously validated, you should never remove the proper validation from the domain. Business invariants are its own responsibility.

As for performance: exceptions have a computational cost, but in most DDD scenarios that I saw till now, they are not a problem. In particular they are not a problem when the commands come from human beings.

**edit**
validation is always responsability of the domain. Take an `ISIN` value object: it's up to its constructor to ensure [its own invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number) by throwing proper exceptions. In a well coded domain, you can't hold an instance of an invalid object. Thus you don't need any validator to cumulate errors.

In the same way, the factories can ensure business invariants if and only if they are the only way to obtain the instance. Technological invariants, such as db column lenght, should be out of the domain, thus a factory could be a good location for them. This would also have the advantage of enabling exceptions' chaining: the SqlExceptions are not much expressive for clients.

With expressive exceptions clients just have to try/catch the exceptions they can handle (and remember that presenting an exception to the user is a way to handle it).

Comment: I agree with you that exceptions should be part of the ubiquitous language (nice post, thank you!), but also that for the sample I'm showing in my post, `Argument(Null)Exception` should be fine. Are you also validation stuff like field lengths in your domain factories, or do you leave that to the database? Can you elaborate? Also, how do you handle all these different exceptions at the client? With all these different exceptions, it sure could be some try/catch block...

Comment: Also, you say to avoid the `CustomerValidator` of sorts, but I see them as a way of collecting errors (while validating the whole object, not just single attributes like the Entity itself does). For example I'll run this validator against the object to be persisted and if errors are found, they are all collected and thrown in an exception.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think that I agree with you. I will however leave the question open for some time hoping that others will comment on this as well, just to get more input.

Answer (score 0):

There is a point at which data comes into your system.  That may be in the form of action arguments (view model) or parameters in a services layer.
You must always hyper-validate at this point (make everything nullable then dis-allow nulls, check for negative numbers on integers, etc) and garuntee that everything is 100% correct at these entry points.  Then the rest of your system doesn't have to worry about it unless the validation is for a particular edge case.
Client validation is nice, but you must never rely on it completely.  There can be a disconnect in the validation at times.  Also, there's not a promise that the clients that are calling your actions are the clients you think they are (e.g. we've all changed a query parameter in a url to see what happens).

My problem with the code that you posted is the fact that there is, at that point, data in your domain that may or may not be valid.  If you always perform validations at the external bounds of your process, you never have to worry. Also, you never end up wondering, "Where did I place that validation?"

Comment: The thing is that there is more to validation than property validation. E.g. you can't check exclusively on the properties in your DTO if "customer has enough credit to perform this purchase", because it may require information from different contexts. So my concern is if such validations of business rules should just trow exceptions or if we should find a more "friendly" way.